# How to determine a list of number is increasing, decreasing or unordered just by using simple operator instead of array, map or other function?

Tags: c

Below is the code that I used to determined the list of number order(increase, decrease or unordered).
Or is there any other simpler mathematical way to determine that a list of number is unordered instead of using 3 variables?

Edit : 1. The list might have duplicated number(So ya I need to have a comparison for equal state too. Thanks to those who point it out).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num, counter, a, b, c, pattern, unordered_flag;
    printf("How many number u want to enter? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    
    counter = 0; b = 0; c = 0;
    while(counter < num){
        printf("Enter number [%d] : ",counter+1);
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("a=%d b=%d c=%d pattern=%d\n",a,b,c,pattern); //I used this to check the value of a,b,c and pattern
        if(a>b>c){
            pattern = 99; //i use 99 to represent increasing order
        }
        else if(a<b<c){
            pattern = 11; //i use 11 to represent decreasing order
        }
        else{
            pattern = 55; //i use 55 to represent unordered order
            unordered_flag = 404;
        }
        c = b;
        b = a;
        counter = counter + 1; 
    }
    if (unordered_flag == 404){
        printf("\nThe pattern is : Unordered");
    }
    else if(pattern == 99){
        printf("\nThe pattern is : Increasing");
    }
    else if(pattern == 11)
        printf("\nThe pattern is : Decreasing");
  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: `if(a>b>c)` doesn't do what you think it does. You need `if(a>b && b>c)`

Comment: You just need to compare the first two numbers to see if they're increasing or decreating. Then compare each remaining number to the preceding number to see if it's in the same order as the first two. As soon as the order changes, you can report that it's unordered.

Comment: you need to check for 4 states not only three. The fourth one is : all are equal.

Comment: @Barmar if all are equal it will be hard to call it "unordered"

Comment: @0___________ True. It's also unclear whether "increasing" means strictly increasing or consecutive elements can be equal, e.g. `1 1 2 3 3 4`

Comment: This would greatly benefit from an `enum` instead of magic numbers -- that's what it's there for. This can be seen as a simple state machine.

Comment: @barmar or even `1 1 1 1 1 1 1`. Is it unordered?

Comment: @0___________ I understood that from your previous comment about "all are equal".

Comment: @Barmar sorry, your example confused me

Comment: I said "also" -- that example is another complication.

Comment: All the same is both weakly decreasing and weakly increasing, but as soon as one number is different, you one-way transition to a state of either weakly increasing or decreasing.

Comment: @ ashrafhamil Can the list of numbers contain duplicates?

Comment: @user3386109 Yes it may have duplicate numbers. I already edit the question.  Thanks for pointing that out. 

@0___________ Thanks for pointing that out.

@Barmar Thanks for enlighten me about that `if(a>b>c)` instead of `if(a>b && b>c)` and your second point too. It give me clear idea on how to do it now. Now I am still trying to transform it into code form.

@Neil Thanks. Now I am learning how `enum` works and what does weakly decreasing/increasing means.

Answer (score 0):

This is the concept of [monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). In a finite strongly-ordered list, you could use a finite-state machine.

[image: Monotonic FSM.]

With, (1): a variable to hold 8 states, (practically could be an `enum` or function pointer,) and (2): memory of the last element, one can completely determine, on-line, the next state. A distance of three transitions is the minimum it takes to cover the vertices.

*Edit: A weaker version of this can be made by collapsing the states outlined in blue.

For example, this (very incomplete) state machine might be how one would do it with an `enum`. This is preferable to using integer magic values for readability and debugging.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

/* X-Macro; just lazy. */
#define STATES X(EMPTY), X(ONE), X(STRICT_INCREASE), X(STRICT_DECREASE), \
    X(EQUAL), X(INCREASE), X(DECREASE), X(UNORDERED)

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    struct {
#define X(x) x
        enum { STATES } state;
#undef X
        int prev;
    } sm = { EMPTY, 0 };
#define X(x) #x
    static char *names[] = { STATES };
#undef X
    int success = EXIT_FAILURE;
    (void)argc; /* Unused; `argv` is null-terminated. */
    errno = 0; /* `strtol` on POSIX-compliant systems gives more info. */
    while(*(++argv)) {
        /* Read a parameter from the command line. */
        char *end;
        int num;
        long temp = strtol(argv[0], &end, 0);
        if(errno) goto catch;
        if(temp < INT_MIN || temp > INT_MAX)
            { errno = ERANGE; goto catch; }
        if(*end != '\0')
            { errno = EILSEQ; goto catch; }
        num = (int)temp;
        /* Plug the parameter into the state machine. */
        switch(sm.state) {
        case EMPTY:
            sm.state = ONE; break;
        case ONE:
            if(sm.prev < num) sm.state = STRICT_INCREASE;
            else if(num < sm.prev) sm.state = STRICT_DECREASE;
            else sm.state = EQUAL;
            break;
        case STRICT_INCREASE: /**** TODO! ****/
        case STRICT_DECREASE:
        case EQUAL:
        case INCREASE:
        case DECREASE:
            sm.state = UNORDERED; break;
        case UNORDERED:
            break;
        }
        sm.prev = num;
    }
    printf("This is %s.\n", names[sm.state]);
    { success = EXIT_SUCCESS; goto finally; }
catch:
    perror("list-of-ints");
finally:
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Interesting!  The OP's solution (using multiple variables with crazy "flag values" like "99" and "11") ... is just wrong.  You're correct: one "state variable" that's an "enum" is absolutely the correct way to go.  But whether we need a full-fledged FSM .. or just a simple "while()" loop - that's for the OP to decide.