# Need to check if array is sorted using a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting

Basically, we need to check if the elements of an 1D array are sorted using a function:
if they are sorted in an ascending order: return 1
if they are sorted in an descending order: return -1
if they are not sorted: return 0
This is the method im using, however it doesnt return 1 but isntead 0, Im unsure where is the problem, Any comments or new methods of solving the problem are welcome since im a beginner.

```
int Is_Sorted(int* A, int n){
    int tempcr, tempdcr;

for (int i=0; i<N-1; i++){

    if (A[i]<=A[i+1]){
        tempcr++;
    }else if (A[i]>=A[i+1]){
    tempdcr++;
    }
}
   if(tempcr==N-1){
        return 1;
   }else if(tempdcr==N-1)
        return -1;
   else
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `tempcr` and `temdcr` are not initialised. Means that they can contain any garbage value to start off with.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any better way of solving this problem?

Comment: The algorithm could be optimised. Don't need to always check the whole array. Can return as soon as you see the order change. Keep track of the order of the first two elements. If it changes return 0. If it gets to the end of the array without changing then return that order.

Comment: It can be done without having to traverse the whole array (in case of unsorted). Once you detect the "trend reversal" you can conclude it is unsorted.

Comment: What should be the result if all items have the same value? Or if the array contains only one value?

Comment: @Pung What to return if all elements are equal each other?

Comment: Nothing is specified in the given problem in case all elements have the same value or any other case, Also thank you all for the help :)

Comment: Pung, note that `n` in `Is_Sorted(int* A, int n)` is not used in the function.

Comment: To make your code work, you need to A) initialize the counters to 0, as noted by kaylum, and B) remove the first `else`. With the first `else`, when `A[i]` is equal to `A[i+1]`, only `tempcr` will be incremented, but you need both counters to increment.

Comment: This is really similar to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69891191/2472827) that has been asked a fortnight ago.

Comment: @kaylum Interesting [micro-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088040/need-to-check-if-array-is-sorted-using-a-function-in-c/70088262#comment123896651_70088040).  Consider if arrays are typically near ascending/descending, then the extra checks you suggest slow the compare.  IMO, one optimization would check the the end-points.  If they differ, only one order testing needed. IAC, these ideas are all O(n) complexity and do not reduce O().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
int Is_Sorted( const int* A, size_t n );
```

that is at least the first parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the passed array is not being changed within the function.

The variables `tempcr` and `tempdcr` were not initialized and have indeterminate values. So the function has undefined behavior. You have to initialize them like

```
int tempcr = 0, tempdcr = 0;
```

There is no sense to continue iterations of the loop if it is already known that the array is unsorted because it is inefficient.

Moreover the function has a logical bug.

Consider the array `{ 0, 0, -1 }`

In this case in the first iteration of the loop the variable `tempcr` will be increased due to the if statement

```
if (A[i]<=A[i+1]){
    tempcr++;
}else if (A[i]>=A[i+1]){
tempdcr++;
}
```

But in the second iteration of the loop the variable `tempdcr` will be increased.

So the function will report that the array is unsorted though it is sorted in the descending order.

I would define the function the following way

```
int is_sorted( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t ascending = 0, descending = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; ( ascending == 0 || descending == 0 ) && i < n; i++)
    {
        if ( a[i-1] < a[i] ) ++ascending;
        else if ( a[i] < a[i-1] ) ++descending;
    }

    return descending == 0 ? 1 : ( ascending == 0 ? -1 : 0 );
}
```

If the passed array has all elements equal each other then the function considers it as sorted in the ascending order.

As pointed **@chux - Reinstate Monica** in his answer instead of counting elements you can use the corresponding variables as boolean objects. In this case the function can look like

```
int is_sorted1( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    int ascending = 0, descending = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; ( ascending == 0 || descending == 0 ) && i < n; i++)
    {
        if ( a[i-1] < a[i] ) ascending = 1;
        else if ( a[i] < a[i-1] ) descending = 1;
    }

    return descending == 0 ? 1 : ( ascending == 0 ? -1 : 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Wrong logic**

OP's code fails due to

```
}else if (A[i]>=A[i+1]){
tempdcr++;
```

should be

```
}
if (A[i]>=A[i+1]) {
  tempdcr++;
```

Consider the case when `A[i]==A[i+1]`, both counters should increment.

**Junk Values**

Missing initialization [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088040/need-to-check-if-array-is-sorted-using-a-function-in-c/70088262#comment123896582_70088040).

```
// int tempcr, tempdcr;
int tempcr = 0;
int tempdcr = 0;
```

---

Alternative approach:

There are 4 possibilities

- Array has the same value value every where - or is of length 0.
- Array is ascending. `A[i] >= A[i-1]` for all `i > 0` and length is more than 0.
- Array is descending. `A[i] <= A[i-1]` for all `i > 0` and length is more than 0.
- None of the above.

Simply loop and adjust two flags.  `int tempcr, tempdcr;` counters not needed.

```
int Is_Sorted(const int* A, int n) {
  bool isAscending = true;
  bool isDescending = true;
  for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) { // start at 1
     if (A[i] < A[i-1]) isAscending = false;
     if (A[i] > A[i-1]) isDescending = false;
  }
  if (isAscending && isDescending) {
    return TBD; // Unsure what OP wants here
  }
  if (isAscending) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (isDescending) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Simplifications and some micro optimization possible, but something to clarify a clear approach.

---

Too much fun.

If `int a[]` is not constant, we can only use 1 test per iteration instead of 3: *test i*, *is less*, *is more* of the above code.

First look for inequality from the end toward the beginning.  The first element is adjusted to be different from the last.

If we walk the entire list, we are done, otherwise the first part of the list differs from the last element.

If the last compare is ascending, set the first element to `INT_MAX` and search toward the beginning for a non-ascending pair.

Otherwise
If the last compare is descending, set the first element to `INT_MIN` and search toward the beginning for a non-descending pair.

Upon finding a compare failure occurs, either the array is unordered or we are at the beginning.  If at the beginning, handle that special case.

In any case, only 1 compare per iteration.

```
#define ASCENDING 1
#define DESCENDING -1
#define UNORDERED 0
#define ALLSAME 1 // Adjust as desired
#define SHORT_LENGTH 1 // Adjust as desired

int is_sorted(size_t n, int *a) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return n ? ALLSAME : SHORT_LENGTH;
  }

  int last = a[--n];
  int first = a[0];
  a[0] = !last;
  while (last == a[--n]) {
    ;
  }
  a[0] = first; // restore
  if (n == 0) {
    if (a[0] < a[1]) {
      return ASCENDING;
    }
    if (a[0] > a[1]) {
      return DESCENDING;
    }
    return ALLSAME;
  }

  if (a[n - 1] < a[n]) {
    // Only ascending, unordered possible
    a[0] = INT_MAX;
    while (a[n - 1] <= a[n]) {
      n--;
    }
    a[0] = first; // restore
    if (a[n - 1] <= a[n]) {
      return ASCENDING;
    }
  } else {
    // Only descending, unordered possible
    a[0] = INT_MIN;
    while (a[n - 1] <= a[n]) {
      n--;
    }
    a[0] = first; // restore
    if (a[n - 1] <= a[n]) {
      return DESCENDING;
    }
  }
  return UNORDERED;
}
```

I'll do some more testing later.

If the array is `const`, need 2 test per loop.

Comment: You can break out of the `for` loop once (if) both flags become `false`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError True, yet that is not a certain optimization as it could also slow the run time as it is doing more checking.   Depends of typical array sets.  IAC, it does not reduce O().  More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088040/need-to-check-if-array-is-sorted-using-a-function-in-c/70088262#comment123897241_70088040).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError For fun, it might be interesting to bi-sect the array at each compare step and check the end points until down to size 1.  Certainly slower in the worst case, but likely to catch early non-ordered arrays and allow for single order compare and/or end-early code.

Comment: For large arrays, or if the code is generalized to match `qsort()` or `bsearch()`, the early break is likely to be beneficial for performance — it avoids potentially many function calls.  When the data type is `int`, the overhead of comparison is much smaller, so the early break vs extra testing is not so clear cut.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError So I had some fun to only use 1 compare per loop.

Comment: Is [this](https://tio.run/##ZczBCoJAFIXhvU9xMAIFC8Ol1aaEhGjAchERIY7apXEmnGklPrspFC1a/t@Bk89ykcmq7yckc/HiBZaCajJ6fl9bP9OG86L8M1IjWcszSxMc2T49xeyADdtG2EVJBEeQfKAqjIZRCkLJClQixveEjIvhgKRBnZF0XLQWMKbECkH4iewSXIdufQ8LD343@rMZltKxp9z2QPqmVWMK7kgPmeuGVtf3bw) a correct way to finish your program and test it? (I'm rusty in C)